# MP3 Playing with NAudio - Problems with Stop()

Tags: naudio

I've just started using NAudio (1.4) solely for MP3 playback. I've been working off the documentation and the source code for the samples. Currently I have this in a class:

```
    IWavePlayer waveOutDevice;
    WaveStream mainOutputStream;
    WaveChannel32 volumeStream;

    public AudioPlaybackService() : base() {
        waveOutDevice = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 100);    
    }

    public bool LoadTrack(string trackPath, float volume)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(trackPath))
            return false;
        try
        {
            mainOutputStream = new Mp3FileReader(trackPath);
            volumeStream = new WaveChannel32(mainOutputStream);
            volumeStream.Volume = volume;
            waveOutDevice.Init(mainOutputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Failed to load track for playback {0} :: {1}", trackPath, e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool PlayTrack()
    {
        if (waveOutDevice == null || waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            return false;
        waveOutDevice.Play();
        return true;
    }

    public bool StopTrack()
    {
        if (waveOutDevice == null || waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
            return false;
        waveOutDevice.Stop();
        mainOutputStream.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        return true;
    }
```

This loads and plays my test track fine, my issue is with the Stop() function. Firstly should I need to reset the CurrentTime property after calling Stop()? Currently it acts more like a pause button i.e. it resumes the track in the same place it was "stopped". If I do need to reset the CurrentTime I now have a problem where if I click stop, the track stops, but if I click play again afterwards I get a little leftover noise before the track starts again.

Looking at the source code of one of the samples all it does is call Stop().

Comment: Have you tried with any of the WaveOut options instead? There is very little reason to use WasapiOut. I'm surprised you get leftover audio since WasapiOut should call audioClient.Reset() when Stop is called which should completely flush any existing buffered audio for playback.

Comment: I've swapped to WaveOut (Method 2 from the codeplex wiki page) now due to having to support XP as well, but still get left over audio with that.

Answer (score 0):

In [our use of naudio](http://radiotuna.com/OnlineRadioPlayer/Intro), we never stop the audio. Any stop-like functionality causes a silent waveform (zeroes) to be fed to the wave out. This was mainly due to instability in naudio when stopping and starting too frequently, but it also prevents the "leftover buffer" problem.

Comment: Thanks. So instead of stopping you swap to playing silence? If the user clicks play (perhaps slightly different for your radio streaming) does it load the stream again or use the same one with the time reset?

Comment: We had to write our own MP3 frame parser with no seek powers, so I'm not well positioned to answer this question. I simply don't know what's best.

Comment: Well I'll have a further play around and see if I can get it working for me.